# Snowflake: SELECT * FROM VALUES syntax

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake supports [VALUES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values) clause:

> In the SELECT statement, the VALUES sub-clause of the FROM clause allows the specification of a set of constants to be used to form a finite set of rows.
>
> ```
> SELECT ...
> FROM ( VALUES ( <expr> [ , <expr> [ , ... ] ] ) [ , ( ... ) ] ) [ [ AS ] <table_alias> [ ( <column_alias> [, ... ] ) ] ]
> ```

The documentation and all provided examples uses `SELECT * FROM (VALUES (<col>));`. Please note parenthesis around `(VALUES())`

```
SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
-- 7.32.1

SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (1),(2));
-- COLUMN1
-- 1
-- 2
```

Though it is also possible to skip them entirely:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VALUES (1),(2);
-- COLUMN1
-- 1
-- 2
```

[image]

None of major RDBMSes seems to support omitting parenthesis **[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/70q8mWJT)**

It is either an undefined behavior or an undocumented feature. I am looking for any reference in Snowflake docs for such syntax/alternatively other SQL dialects which also support it.

Answer (score 0):

Well is "just follows" imho from the fact as statement can be:

```
select 1 as a;
```

[image]

and thus we can have a sub-select:

```
select a from
(
    select 1 as a
);
```

[image]

and we can also put the "values" into that sub-select:

```
select a from 
(
    values
        (10),
        (11)
) as t(a);
```

[image]

thus a `values ()+` is the same as a `select thing+`

now, CTE's are also valid start of statements:

```
with cte_a as (
    select 1 as a
)
select * from cte_a;
```

as are cte's in cte's:

```
with cte_a as (
    with cte_b as (
        select 1 as a
    )
    select * from cte_b
)
select * from cte_a;
```

but this does not explain the validness of the "lack of parens". But more, the recursive nature of the grammar, thus there must be something, that considers VALUES by itself as complete.

now [Oracle's grammar](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj11277.html) has the parens, but in the INSERT example, the parans is not present:

```
-- insert a row with a DEFAULT value for the MAJPROJ column
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJNO, PROJNAME, DEPTNO, RESPEMP, PRSTDATE, MAJPROJ) 
VALUES ('PL2101', 'ENSURE COMPAT PLAN', 'B01', '000020', CURRENT_DATE, DEFAULT)
```

that is just one row, albeit, the example above also does not require the parens around the multi line INSERT.

Looking at Snowflake's [INSERT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert) it's grammar does not have the parens around the VALUES

[image]

So I assume is a unification of these two grammars, and not being sticklers. Which can be seen all the way back to that `select 1 as a;` Oracle would require a `from dual` which adds not value, and just adds clutter. Other  RDBMSes do not require a from table.

Comment: I am not convinced to the SELECT analogy, if it is supposed like this then `SELECT * FROM SELECT 1 As c` should also work.  A more similar analogy would be independent `VALUES` clause:  `VALUES(1),(2);` and `SELECT * FROM VALUES (1),(2);` should be supported - [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9RWaCt5M).

Comment: It obviously works in Snowflake without the parentheses. If you think the documentation is wrong then just raise it with Snowflake Support and they'll (probably) get it amended

Comment: @LukaszSzozda the select analogy was more saying "this is how I see a select block is constructed" and here are patterns of  things that are "valid here", and then the look INSERT does not need the parens around values. So if the grammar is shared, that could be the source of the undocumented grammar allowance. myself I would be anoyed if parens had to be added, as they add zero scoping value.